# Substituting multiple (but not all) occurences of a pattern using AWK's gensub() function

Tags: awk

This example removes the fifth occurrence of a regular expression:

```
printf "%s " $(seq 9) | gawk '{ print gensub(/[0-9]/,"","5") }'
1 2 3 4  6 7 8 9
```

This example removes the sixth instance of a regular expression:

```
printf "%s " $(seq 9) | gawk '{ print gensub(/[0-9]/,"","6") }'
1 2 3 4 5  7 8 9
```

Is possible to save the above examples in one?
I tried it, but it does not work:

```
printf "%s " $(seq 9) | gawk '{ print gensub(/[0-9]/,"","5|6") }'
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I want printed:

```
1 2 3 4    7 8 9
```

Comment: Why are you using an END condition? It's not appropriate for what you're doing in your example and in some awks the last record read isn't even available in the END section.

Comment: @EdMorton, You're right, the condition "END" is not needed. Printf prints all on one line. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Why did you mention "printf"? It's not used in your example and has nothing to do with my comment so I wonder if there was there some misunderstanding of what I was saying.

Comment: I wrote about the "printf", because the first time I used this example -> `seq -s " " 9 | gawk -v ORS="" '{if(i!=5&&i!=6) print gensub(/[0-9]/,"","5") }END{print "\n"}'` The second time I used this example -> `printf "%s " $(seq 9) | gawk 'END{ print gensub(/[0-9]/,"","5") }'` In the second example, I've forgotten delete condition "END".
You wrote about the condition of END in another sense. Now it is all clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), the one of the ways I can think of:

```
printf "%s " $(seq 9) | gawk 'END{ print gensub(/[0-9]/,"","5",gensub(/[0-9]/,"","5")) }'
```

And another way (with your very specific input):

```
printf "%s " $(seq 9) | gawk 'END { print gensub(/[0-9] [0-9]/,"","3") }'
```

> Search the target string target for matches of the regular expression
>   regexp. If *how* is a string beginning with ‘g’ or ‘G’ (short for
>   “global”), then replace all matches of regexp with replacement.
>   **Otherwise, how is treated as a number indicating which match of regexp
>   to replace.** If no target is supplied, use $0. It returns the modified
>   string as the result of the function and the original target string is
>   not changed.

Comment: Thank your example. It works, but then you have to use twice gensub. Is it possible to do the same, but use only once gensub? That's one way -> `printf "%s " $(seq 9) | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i!=5&&i!=6) {printf "%s ",i}else{printf "%s ",""} print ""}'`

Comment: Added solution with single gensub invocation.